# Search two columns of a table, one hidden but show whole row with results

Tags: jquery, html-table, hidden

Is it possible to search two columns of a table and one of them be hidden from sight? I want to search both columns but column 2 be hidden and if there are any matches I want to see column 1.

This is what I've been attempting to use:

```
<html>
<head>
 <style>
 #myTable tr td:nth-child(2){
    display: none;
}
 </style>
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
 </script>
 </head>
<body>

<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search 
by any part of name or speed code" title="Type in a name">
 <br/>
<table id="myTable">

    <tr>
    <td>Albert Einstein College of Medicine</td>
    <td>cardiac</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Bronx Lebanon Hospital Center</td>
    <td>labor</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Jacobi Medical Center</td>
    <td>stemi</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Lincoln Medical Center</td>
    <td>stroke</td>
    <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script>
var mylist = $('#myTable');
var listitems = mylist.find('tr');
listitems.sort(function(a, b) {
   return 
$(a).text().toUpperCase().localeCompare($(b).text().toUpperCase());
})
$.each(listitems, function(idx, itm) { mylist.append(itm); });
</script>
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }       
  }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

You can ignore this but it's the TL;DR part because they won't let me post without adding more crap. Basically I want to see only column 1 but search column 1 and 2 for a result. If results match the input box of column 1 or 2 I want to see column 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed the following code, so now it also searches in all `td` in each `tr`.

```
td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
if (td) {
  var t = false;
  $.each(td, function(i,x) {
    if (x.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      t = true;
    } 

  })
  tr[i].style.display = t ? "" : "none";
}
```

**Demo**

```js
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
    if (td) {
      var t = false;
      $.each(td, function(i, x) {
        if (x.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
          t = true;
        }

      })
      tr[i].style.display = t ? "" : "none";
    }
  }
}

var mylist = $('#myTable');
var listitems = mylist.find('tr');
listitems.sort(function(a, b) {
  return
  $(a).text().toUpperCase().localeCompare($(b).text().toUpperCase());
})
$.each(listitems, function(idx, itm) {
  mylist.append(itm);
});
```

```css
#myTable tr td:nth-child(2) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search 
by any part of name or speed code" title="Type in a name">
<br/>
<table id="myTable">

  <tr>
    <td>Albert Einstein College of Medicine</td>
    <td>cardiac</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Bronx Lebanon Hospital Center</td>
    <td>labor</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jacobi Medical Center</td>
    <td>stemi</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lincoln Medical Center</td>
    <td>stroke</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Looks like that's all I needed. Thank you.